# Mock method which returns same value passed as argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

How do I mock python method using python `unittest.mock` which will return same value passed as argument,

I tried,

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def dummy_function(value):
    "Will return same value as value passed to the function"
    return value

# To moke gettext function used in template
# Then I pass this mock method to Jinja2 template to moke gettext string
_ = MagicMock(return_value=dummy_function)
```

When I print the jinja template it displays test something like below,

```
<div class="order_details">\n                
<legend class="badge">&lt;function dummy_function at 0x10887f730&gt;</legend>\n            
</div>\n
```

Orignal Jinja2 template has

```
<div class="order_details">             
<legend class="badge">_('Details')</legend>           
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`return_value` is only ever a *fixed object* to return, and you just told the mock that the result of a call is a function object.

You want to use the [`side_effect` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) instead:

```
_ = MagicMock(side_effect=dummy_function)
```

Setting `side_effect` to a function causes it to be called *with the same arguments as the mock*. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect):

> If you pass in a function it will be called with same arguments as the mock and unless the function returns the `DEFAULT` singleton the call to the mock will then return whatever the function returns.

Demo:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> identity = lambda a: a
>>> MagicMock(return_value=identity)('called')  # returns the function object, it won't call it
<function <lambda> at 0x10fa61620>
>>> MagicMock(side_effect=identity)('called')   # will call the function
'called'
```

Answer (score 0):

You directly passed the function object as return value, that's why it prints the function's `repr`(name and memory address). You need to pass the actual value you want as return, so:

```
_ = MagicMock(return_value=dummy_function(somevalue))
```

But if the function always return the value passed it is useless, creating a mock is already enough so may be just do:

```
_ = MagicMock(return_value=somevalue)
```

Then call your mock as you would.

*Sidenote: What is the purpose of the `_` usage instead of a name? Are you mocking gettext ? If not or would be cleaner to give the mock a name, the best IMO is to name the mock like the real function you are mocking for explicitness.*